# Remove http of url for displaying website addresses in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, each supplier has a website address which is displayed on their supplier show page (value is @supplier.website).

If the website url begins with http:// I'd like to remove this from the view page i.e. rather than displaying http://www.google.com it would just display www.google.com (but the actual @supplier.website will remain unchanged).

Hope that makes sense, and that someone can help...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a URI parse.

```
uri = URI.parse 'http://google.com/whatever'
uri.host #=> 'google.com'
uri.path #=> '/whatever'
```

Best to make a helper

```
def website_link_text(uri)
  URI.parse(uri).host
end
```

And then in the view:

```
<%= link_to website_link_text(@supplier.website), @supplier.website %>
```